# Npm install pomelo errors VC++ 2010?

Tags: c++, node.js

I tried to run
npm install pomelo -g

I got this:

```
...
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pomelo-schedule/0.3.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pomelo-logger/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/0.4.25
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-bignumber/1.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pomelo-protobuf/0.4.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cliff/0.1.8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/2.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js/0.6.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ndump
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js/0.6.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pomelo-loader/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-pkg/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/1.4.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0

> toobusy@0.2.2 install C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\toobusy
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\toobusy>node "D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\toobusy
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ndump
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pomelo-loader/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-pkg/0.0.5

> ndump@0.0.2 install C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-admin\node_modules\ndump
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-admin\node_modules\ndump>node "D:\Logiciels insta
llés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200

gyp ERR! command "node" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-admin\node_modules\ndump
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/1.4.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\re
dis\diff_multi_bench_output.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\redis\diff_multi_be
nch_output.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\redis\diff_
multi_bench_output.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\stream-p
kg'
File exists: C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\stream-pkg
Move it away, and try again.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\stream-pkg
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\stream-pkg
\.npmignore
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-schedule\node_modu
les\log4js\test\categoryFilter-test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-schedule\node_modules\log4js\test\c
ategoryFilter-test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-schedule\node_modules\log4j
s\test\categoryFilter-test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\cliff\node_modules\winsto
n\lib\winston\common.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\cliff\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\com
mon.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\cliff\node_modules\winston\lib\win
ston\common.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\p
omelo-loader\README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\pomelo-loader\READ
ME.md
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\pomelo-loa
der\README.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\socket
.io\node_modules\policyfile\doc\index.html'
npm ERR! error rolling back  pomelo@0.8.1 { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\no
de_modules\socket.io\node_modules\policyfile\doc\index.html']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\Vadorequest\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pomelo\\node_modules\\socket.io\
\node_modules\\policyfile\\doc\\index.html' }
npm ERR! toobusy@0.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the toobusy@0.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the toobusy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls toobusy
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\po
licyfile\doc\index.html'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\policyfile\doc\inde
x.html
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\policyfile\
doc\index.html
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-admin\node_modules
\socket.io-client\components\learnboost-engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-jsonp.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-admin\node_modules\socket.io-client
\components\learnboost-engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-jsonp.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-admin\node_modules\socket.i
o-client\components\learnboost-engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-jsonp.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-logger\node_module
s\log4js\.bob\instrumented\test\dateFileAppender-test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-logger\node_modules\log4js\.bob\ins
trumented\test\dateFileAppender-test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-logger\node_modules\log4js\
.bob\instrumented\test\dateFileAppender-test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\n
ode-uuid\uuid.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
s" "install" "pomelo" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vadorequest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\node-uuid\uuid.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Vadorequest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pomelo\node_modules\pomelo-rpc\node_modules\node-uuid\
uuid.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack D:\Logiciels installés\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

My computer is new and I thing it's because of C++ redistibuable but I just installed VC++ 2010 redistribuable and reboot my computer. Any idea? Thx.

Comment: Could be related to python issue https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/277

Comment: Thanks. I changed only the ENV variables, create a PYTHON_PATH and a PYTHON=%PYTHON_PATH%/python.exe and that seems work. But I got a VC++ error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Python
PYTHON=%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe
```

Instead of

```
PYTHON=C:\Python\python.exe
```

Will fix Python.

I also installed Visual Studio 2012 Pro (but express 2010 should work too)
VC++ fixed.

Pomelo installed correctly then.
Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me to remove the folder `C:\Users\YourName\.node-gyp`  and of course this is for windows only.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the required software to run `node-gyp`:

- https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

You can configure version of Visual Studio used by `gyp` via an environment variable>

Examples:

- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2012` for Visual Studio 2012
- set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013e` (the 'e' stands for 'express edition')

For the full list see 
 - https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.29/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py#L209-294

This is still painful for Windows users of NodeJS as it assumes you have a copy of Visual Studio installed and many end users will never have this. So I'm lobbying Joyent to the encourage them to include web sockets as part of CORE node and also to possible ship a GNU gcc compiler as part of NodeJS install so we can permanently fix this problem.

Feel free to add your vote at:

- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8005#issuecomment-50545326

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Pomelo in Windows; I tried but I failed. Another solution is clone the folder (lib) that Pomelo was installed in in Ubuntu, and paste it to the `node_modules` folder of your project, as shown here:
[image: Pomelo]

And now you can clone Pomelo sample projects to try it. I had success with this solution.

Here is Pomelo that was compiled from the Ubuntu that I used:
[Pomelo folder compiled on Ubuntu](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hxz6ee5n8_TEtzdllzZGo5bjg/view?usp=sharing)